# C++ circular include

Tags: c++, header, compiler-errors, circular-dependency

I can't solve this circular dependency problem; always getting this error:
"invalid use of incomplete type struct GemsGame"
I don't know why the compiler doesn't know the declaration of GemsGame even if I included gemsgame.h
Both classes depend on each other (GemsGame store a vector of GemElements, and GemElements need to access this same vector)

Here is partial code of GEMELEMENT.H:

```
#ifndef GEMELEMENT_H_INCLUDED
#define GEMELEMENT_H_INCLUDED

#include "GemsGame.h"

class GemsGame;

class GemElement {
    private:
        GemsGame* _gemsGame;

    public:
        GemElement{
            _gemsGame = application.getCurrentGame();
            _gemsGame->getGemsVector();
        }
};


#endif // GEMELEMENT_H_INCLUDED
```

...and of GEMSGAME.H:

```
#ifndef GEMSGAME_H_INCLUDED
#define GEMSGAME_H_INCLUDED

#include "GemElement.h"

class GemsGame {
    private:
        vector< vector<GemElement*> > _gemsVector;

    public:
        GemsGame() {
            ...
        }

        vector< vector<GemElement*> > getGemsVector() {
            return _gemsVector;
        }
}

#endif // GEMSGAME_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: If you have a forward declaration, you shouldn't also include it. And from what you've shown, both only need a forward declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `#include` directives, you already have the classes forward declared.

If your class A needs, in its definition, to know something about the particulars of class B, then you need to include class B's header. If class A only needs to know that class B exists, such as when class A only holds a pointer to class B instances, then it's enough to forward-declare, and in that case an `#include` is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you deference the pointer and the function is inline you will need the full type. If you create a cpp file for the implementation you can avoid the circular dependecy (since neither of the class will need to include each others .h in their headers)

Something like this:

your header:

```
#ifndef GEMELEMENT_H_INCLUDED
#define GEMELEMENT_H_INCLUDED

class GemsGame;

class GemElement {
    private:
        GemsGame* _gemsGame;

    public:
        GemElement();
};


#endif // GEMELEMENT_H_INCLUDED
```

your cpp:

```
#include "GenGame.h"
GenElement::GenElement()
{
   _gemsGame = application.getCurrentGame();
   _gemsGame->getGemsVector();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways out:

1. Keep the dependent classes in the same H-file
2. Turn dependency into abstract interfaces: GemElement implementing IGemElement and expecting for IGemsGame, and GemsGame implementing IGemsGame and containing a vector of IGemElement pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the top answer of this topic: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

He really explains everything you need to know about forward declarations and what you can and cannot do with classes that you forward declare.

It looks like you are using a forward declaration of a class and then trying to declare it as a member of a different class. This fails because using a forward declaration makes it an incomplete type.